# Python IDEs that come with a Python Interpreter Installed?

Tags: python-2.7

Is there an IDE that I can download that doesn't require manual download of Python 2.7? I know how to download everything and I have PyCharm but I just would like to know if it exists.

Comment: questions asking to find tools is off topic for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download and install anaconda it is available for windows,os x & Linux.
You don't need to install python separately for it.
https://www.continuum.io/downloads